# How to completely uninstall Python 2.7 on Windows 10?

Tags: python

as Python 3 is out I'd like to completely uninstall 2.7 on windows 10 64 bit. How can I achieve this?

Comment: isn't there an uninstall procedure already?

Comment: Start -> Settings -> Apps and features -> select Python -> uninstall?

Comment: I heard you had to remove the paths?

Comment: You don't really need to do that. I have Python 3.6 and Python 2.7 side by side and it works perfectly. You just have to be careful when you install 3rd party libraries: you have to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Removing paths and using the installer to uninstall solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python installations can be very difficult to remove on Windows. If you delete some of the obvious content, the Python Launcher for Windows may still run, but it won't be able to complete the uninstall successfully.

I installed the free [IObit Uninstaller], searched for all programs with py in the name, and was finally able to remove my old versions.